How can I make slider work correctly if it gets scaled with transform:scale()
I have a jQWidget slider on a page, but the same problem exists with the jQuery slider. If I set a transform: scale(0.7) to any element above in the hierarchy, the slider does show not the correct visual value and sliding is not synchronous with the mouse position.
How can I solve this? My goal is to scale a div that contains multiple sliders but other elements too.
What is interesting: If the I put the the container into an iframe, and scale it, the slider works as expected. Why is that and would that be an acceptable approach, zooming the container (I guess not)?


  $( function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
  } );
#slider {
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="slider"></div>




Could you clarify why it is being transformed, scaled down? There are other ways to make it smaller.

@Twisty Actually, I have the requirement to scale the whole page, bypassing any usual responsiveness features of CSS. It is like zooming of the browser. Just resize anything. I found out that an iframe does the job perfectly, afaik, but using iframes seems to me like a workaround. For some reason, it seems to be a problem that is present with other libraries as well (e.g. devexpress).

Can use CSS Theming and scale down the values.


$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    classes: {
      "ui-slider": "s70 ui-corner-all",
      "ui-slider-handle": "s70 ui-corner-all",
    }
  });
});
.ui-slider.s70 {
  width: 70%;
  height: calc(.8em * .7);
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle.s70 {
  width: calc(1.2em * .7);
  height: calc(1.2em * .7);
  top: -.2em;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="slider"></div>



